# Fucos in event handling for pyqt Main window

Tags: python, pyqt, focus

I'm using pyqt 4.10 in python 2.7 and I have the main window and I want a function to be called when the window loses focus and get it again.

the function is :

```
def focusInEvent(self, event):
    print 'focus in event'
    conn = sqlite3.connect('storage/container.db')
    conn.row_factory = lambda c, row: row[0]
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT category_name FROM categories")
    category_all = c.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    self.comboBox.clear()
    self.comboBox.addItems(category_all)
    super(mainWindow, self).focusInEvent(event)
```

Changing window focus does nothing, my question is .. to call the function I should use some signal like `triggered` or `connect`?

or the function works as an event that is already triggered when the condition ( which is having focus in ) happens

and if there is a signal to use. what is it!

### Update

Tried to do it like this :

```
class EventFilter(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, parent)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        global comboBox
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.ActivationChange:
            if self.parent().isActiveWindow():
                print "got the focus"
            conn = sqlite3.connect('storage/container.db')
            conn.row_factory = lambda c, row: row[0]
            c = conn.cursor()
            c.execute("SELECT category_name FROM categories")
            category_all = c.fetchall()
            conn.close()
            comboBox.clear()
            comboBox.addItems(category_all)
        return QtCore.QObject.eventFilter(self, obj, event)
mainWindow.installEventFilter(EventFilter(mainWindow))
```

and it returned the error :

```
got the focus
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\townoftechwarehouse\Warehouse.py", line 641, in eventFilter
    comboBox.clear()
NameError: global name 'comboBox' is not defined
got the focus
```

which mean I successfully caught the focus in event, but can't see the variable from outside the class of event filter, how to call the var in there !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by having a function that does what I need to do when I get focusIn, here it is :

```
def refreshing():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('storage/container.db')
    conn.row_factory = lambda c, row: row[0]
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT category_name FROM categories")
    category_all = c.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    self.comboBox.clear()
    self.comboBox.addItems(category_all)
```

Then I called it in the event filter:

```
class EventFilter(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, parent)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        global comboBox
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.ActivationChange:
            if self.parent().isActiveWindow():
                print "got the focus"
                refreshing()
        return QtCore.QObject.eventFilter(self, obj, event)
```

then assigned the event filter to my main window using `mainWindow.installEventFilter(EventFilter(mainWindow))`

and now it works perfectly and I can do whatever I want in the refreshing function